# Manually calling UIRefreshControl and using setContentOffset

Tags: objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I have implemented refreshControl as shown below in viewDidLoad():

```
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
    self.tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl;
} else {
    [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
}
```

Now I am presenting another viewController which has options to select filters. And after selecting those filters you come back again to current viewController having refreshControl.

I have added below code in viewDidAppear() for manually calling beginRefreshing:

```
if (self.filterChanged) {
    self.filterChanged = NO;
    [self.activityTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, - refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    [refreshControl setHidden:NO];
    [refreshControl beginRefreshing];
}
```

I have used setContentOffset for scrolling back to top and showing refreshControl.
The only problem is suppose my tableView is half scrolled in between then there is a big gap between refreshControl.

If my tableView is not scrolled then it works fine like I have pulled down to refresh, but if it is half scrolled then inspite of giving setContentOffset there is a big gap between refreshControl and tableview.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the scroll to finish before you can start the refresh. Unfortunately there is no completion block on `setContentOffset`, so try this.

After creating your refresh control set the target and create a corresponding method.

```
[_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshRequested) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)refreshRequested {
    [_activityTableView reloadData];
}
```

In your `viewDidAppear` you scroll to top and refresh when **done**.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:0 animations:^(void){        
    self.activityTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    [self refreshRequested];
}];
```

When finished loading you need to end refresh and make sure to scroll back to zero position.

```
- (void)finishedLoading {
    [_refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self.activityTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: "Unfortunately there is no completion block on setContentOffset" Actually, yes there is. There's a way to detect when the scroll animation ends.

Comment: I see what you are getting at. Why not share your thoughts in another answer?

Comment: I don't think it's a major issue with your answer. I'm just suggesting that "no completion block" is a bit strong. :)